# Best workflow to manage newsletters subscriptions/unsubscriptions?

Tags: newsletter

I'm trying to figure out what's the best workflow to create and send a newsletter to my subscribers and keep control over subscriptions/unsubscriptions, either by using magento as the primary platform or a third party email marketing platform. My number of subscribers is higher than 3k.

My key point is that magento users/customers can subscribe/unsubscribe the newsletter through their account settings, so managing subscriptions/unsubscriptions should be easy as Magento default newsletter template provides an unsubscribe link.

Meanwhile if I use an email marketing provider, I'd need to create a subscribers list. In case a subscriber wants to unsubscribe, he/she will still appear as subscribed in his/her account settings, so a difference between the Magento and Provider lists will be created (I haven't found a single app in the market that is able to sync between Magento and a Provider's list).

So any ideas on how to work this out will be very welcome.
Frank

Comment: you can try magemail https://magemail.co/